# why doesn't /dev/video1 trigger select?

Tags: c, linux, video, video-capture

I have 2 USB webcams connected to my debian 6 box. One is a `Logitech QuickCam Orbit` and the other is a `Logitech QuickCam 4000 Pro`.

Currently the Orbit shows up as `/dev/video0` and the 4000 Pro as `/dev/video1`.

Both cameras appear to be working fine, that is, I can open both `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` without error. I can query the camera's format using a `video4Linux` `ioctl()`. And I can set their capture format using a `video4linux` `ioctl()`--all without errors.  The drivers appear to be working just fine.

I then setup `select()` for both file descriptors but `select()` never gets triggered for the `/dev/video1` file descriptor.

This is my `select()` related code:

```
FD_ZERO(&readFDS);
FD_SET(nCaptureReadPipeFD, &readFDS);   // this is a control channel for my thread
FD_SET(nCameraOneFD, &readFDS);
if (nNumberOfCameras == 2) FD_SET(nCameraTwoFD, &readFDS);

nReturnCode = select(nSelectFD, &readFDS, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I think I have `select()` correct--I have checked all of the related file descriptors and they correspond to the respective file descriptors returned from the `open()` call. The file descriptor used in the `select()` call, `nSelectFD`, is indeed 1 more than the largest file descriptor.

But still no action from `/dev/video1`

Do I have to deal with major/minor device numbers when using multiple cameras?

Comment: You've omitted important part of the code like where `nSelectFD` was set, but assuming there are no mistakes there, I'm going to guess it might just be a kernel/driver bug. Are you saying video0 works but video1 fails?

Comment: What's your read timout?

Comment: If timeout is NULL , select() can block indefinitely.

Comment: But shouldn't if there's input available...

Comment: the timeout is NULL so the select() blocks until there is data available for reading.  The file descriptor for /dev/video0 triggers select() just fine. That is, select() returns for that file descriptor and I can read data from /dev/video0 just fine. But I never get the select() for /dev/video1 to trigger.

Comment: Well, if blocking was your intent, Then the assumption is you coded to handle it and the code fragment looks correct. Can you get data from video1 with a standard utility? Mojor/minor shouldn't be an issue. The problem is probably somewhere else in your code or ( as R. ) suggested, a kernel glitch.